# NTFS5: No grldr | Cannot find GRLDR

Tags: grub, bios, boot, mbr

Вот, что появляется все время (зацикленно, но иногда заходит в BIOS после нажатия запрашиваемой комбинации клавиш):

[image: сюда иногда заходит]

[image: зациклен тут при включении]

Answer (score 1):

**GRLDR** - это псевдоним / аббревиатура для загрузчика GRUB для Windows (также известный как GRUB4DOS или GRUB for DOS), который часто используется для настройки ПК на двойную загрузку в Windows и одной или нескольких Linux (или другой * nix-based) ) операционных систем.

Такая ошибка может возникать либо сразу после установки дистрибутива Linux, либо в какой-то момент в будущем, когда Automatic Update или Windows Update исправляют файлы загрузчика или сам загрузочный сектор, нарушая конфигурацию на основе GRLDR.

*Вероятные источники проблемы:*

- ваш образ с ОС Windows (на USB или DVD-диске), содержит не легальную версию Windows с использованием хитрости активации SLIC. Этот трюк работает путем перезаписи области памяти, из-за чего Windows считает, что это OEM-установка, устанавливаемая на компьютер от производителя. Эти приложения активации часто используют GRUB4DOS для загрузки соответствующих поддельных строк SLIC в память;
- одноразовая случайность и она будет устранена во время переустановки системы;
- есть вероятность, что старая установка Linux оставила загрузчик, который похоже, мешает системе, когда вы пытаетесь загрузить Windows.

Так как вы так и не отписались в комментариях, о полной ситуации. По поводу количества ОС на вашем ПК и делались ли ранее какие-то манипуляции с системами. Ответ даю лишь исходя из скринов выложенных вами в вопросе.

Рекомендую вам, следующие шаги:

1. Просмотрите документацию дистрибутива Linux, который вы используете или использовали ранее, а также форумы по данному направлению.
2. В ОС Windows [следуйте инструкциям по восстановлению загрузчика](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927392/use-bootrec-exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues) с официального сайта Microsoft.
3. Также есть вариант, с полной очисткой жесткого диска, удалением всех разделов и установки с нуля, но это уже на крайний случай.

*Полезные ссылки по вашей проблеме:*

[Об данной ошибке на Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/355927/uninstalled-ubuntu-no-grldr)
[Cannot find grldr in all devices на Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/189915/cannot-find-grldr-in-all-devices)
[Информация об ошибке при загрузке “no GRLDR” и аналогичных ошибках GRLDR](https://neosmart.net/wiki/cannot-find-grldr/)